# Why do I get this error No exact matches in call to instance method 'scaleEffect'?

Tags: swiftui

Hello as I am a beginner in swiftUI I am currently following a training on the udemy platform but I encounter a problem that I can't solve. As I'm a beginner I still have trouble understanding some errors, if you could please enlighten me in my learning it would be nice I have the following error "No exact matches in call to instance method 'scaleEffect'"

Thanking you in advance

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTY

    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    @State private var ismageScale: CGFloat = 1

    // MARK: - FUNCTION

    // MARK: - CONTENT

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack{
               // MARK - PAGE IMAGE
                Image("magazine-front-cover")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding()
                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius:12, x: 2, y: 2)
                    .opacity(isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
                    .scaleEffect(imageScale)
                    // MARK - 1 TAP Gesture
                    .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                        if imageScale == 1 {
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            imageScale = 5
                        }
                    } else {
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            imageScale = 1
                        }
                    }
                })

            } // ZSTACK
            .navigationTitle("Pinch & Zoom")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                    isAnimating = true
                }
            })
        }  // NAVIGATION
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
being a beginner in swift I did not try to do anything in particular
```

Comment: Typo: ismageScale

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the name of your variable in declaration. Change it to `imageScale`